# MySQL select query custom output

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have a simple select query which gives 2 columns as output with following result

```
name    type
abc.com type1
cde.com type1
cde.com type2
cde.com type2
```

I want to modify my query so that my output at runtime looks as below

```
name    source
abc.com physical
cde.com physical
cde.com vm
cde.com vm
```

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expression.

Comment: While the answers provided (referencing `case`) solve your issue, this is a perfect use case for [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT name, 
CASE WHEN type = 'type1' THEN 'physical' ELSE 'vm' END as source
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use a `case` expression:

```
select name,
       (case when type = 'type1' then 'physical'
             when type = 'type2' then 'vm'
        end) as source
from t;
```

Often, this information would be in a reference table (say `types`) and you would do this lookup using a `join` rather than a `case` expression.

Comment: But where I am referring `type` column?

Comment: @meallhour . . . In the `case` expression.  Look at the `when` conditions.